# EF Core Navigation Property For Left Outer Join?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-6, .net-6.0

I have two tables in SQL.  One of them is named **"Users"** that holds user information and one of them is named **"UserDefaultSources"** that holds default payment sources (tokens).  Not every User has a "UserDefaultSource" however the "AccountId" column is required in the User table and is the primary key in the UserDefaultSources table.

I would like to create a **navigation property** where I can **.Include** the **UserDefaultSource** which would populate the ***UserDefaultSource*** property of the User object when one exists in that table.

This is the SQL that I currently use to query these tables the way I am describing above.

```
SELECT usr.UserId,
       uds.AccountId,
       usr.FirstName,
       usr.LastName
FROM dbo.Users usr (NOLOCK)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UserDefaultSources uds (NOLOCK)
        ON uds.AccountId = usr.AccountId;
```

When I run this code in SSMS I get the following:

[image]

Notice that the **AccountId** column is null in the rows where a UserDefaultSource doesn't exist for that User.

In my **.NET 6 project with EF Core 6** I am trying to create two entities, for these tables and then query the user to include the UserDefaultSource as a navigation property like this.

```
User user = await dbContext.Users
                    .Include(v => v.Region)
                    .Include(v => v.Country)
                    .Include(v => v.Gender)
                    .Include(v=> v.UserDefaultSource)
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(v => v.UserId == userId);
```

This works perfectly for the other associated entities (Region, Country, Gender) because it's a one to one relationship.  How can I get EF Core to **.Include** the UserDefaultSource when a matching record exists in the UserDefaultSources table?

Comment: Please explain how you made User.AccountId required (non nullable?) and foreign keyed it to UserDefaultSource.AccountId pk, and then were able to run a query where the relation failed

Comment: *because it's a one to one relationship* - i wouldn't expect it to be 1:1; I would expect one Region to have many Users? Side note, your database would probably be less confusing int the Pk of UserDefaultSources were called UserDefaultSourceId, and same for the related column in User. **Post your models and context def**

Comment: *I am trying to create two entities* - if the db exists, you can get EF to make the entities. This has the added bonus of them usually being ready to work with as expected without any "argh, why is this not working". I suspect something is wonky in the setup and how EF thinks the db is vs how it actually is has some difference

Comment: can you also share how you have implemented your poco classes?

Comment: There is no foreign key between these tables in SQL.  I want to create the relationship in EF Core to work the same way the SQL works in the example I shared above.

Comment: Do not mix EF6 and EFCore tags, please. EFCore6 != EF6